# how to achieve this in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have two object like Enquery_*c and payment.enquery object have one field like opportunityOrder*_C and payment__c object have tow fields like po_text__x and Po_date.

My requirement  is i enter field opportunityOrder__c and automatically update another object two fields like Po_text__c and Po_date__ was updated automatically.can you please tell me how to solve  this task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the relation between Enquery_c and payment is Master-Detail relationship you can did that by Workflow, else by trigger on enquery__c after Update.

Answer (score 0):

To add more light to Shimpson Korits:

There might be a relationship between Payment and Enquery like lookup or master detail.

If Payment is master/parent (through look up) of Enquery then
 Workflow and trigger are the approaches.

else
 Only trigger can be used for the update.